# Pop-Up Alert do not show

Tags: javascript, php

These are my codes:

```
<?php
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $error = "Wrong Username and Password!";
    $_COOKIE['err']=$error;
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Wrong username or Password")';
    echo '</script>';
    header("Location: HomePage.php");
}else{
    echo "Connected successfully";
    $chckSelect ="SELECT DISTINCT intUsrType FROM trial1232016.tblUser WHERE strUsrName = '".$username."';";
    $result = $conn->query($chckSelect);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo "ends here!";
    }
?>
```

The question is: why does this code, do not generate the alert Wrong username or password. It just redirect to the HomePage.php which is the header...Why does it direct there in an instant without showing the wrong username or password? Can anyone help me?

Comment: you're outputting before header, that's why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Echo is executed but before you can see it
the line

```
header("Location: HomePage.php");
```

cause that everything that is echoed before is not seen as the page is redirected (reloaded again)

To see some change you can:

1. Redirect to page with some

   ```
   header("Location: HomePage.php?invalid");
   ```

   Then in your view check if ?invalid property is set and then show message
2. You can set some $_SESSION variable so that it is not visible in url
3. You can implement some ajax login

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        $error = "Wrong Username and Password!";
        $_SESSION['err']=$error;

        header("Location: HomePage.php");

    }else{
    echo "Connected successfully";
    $chckSelect ="SELECT DISTINCT intUsrType FROM trial1232016.tblUser WHERE strUsrName = '".$username."';";
    $result = $conn->query($chckSelect);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo "ends here!";
    }
```

then in your HomePage.php

```
 if ($_SESSION['err']){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Wrong username or Password")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: this won't work and it contains errors

Comment: Its will work |

Comment: no it won't. A cookie also counts as output. `$_COOKIE['err']=$error;

        header("Location: HomePage.php");`

Comment: You right ,I will fix it to $_SESSION